# No error message is appearing when log in information is incorrect

Tags: magento-1.9, login

When a customer logs in with the incorrect password, we used to have an error message pop up but now it just refreshes the page with no error message and i haven't edited the login.phtml file, could anyone tell me why this is happening, please.

This is my login.phtml

```
<div class="account-login">

    <div class="block block-login">
        <div class="block-slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <div class="block-title">
                        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Sign In') ?></span></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-content">

                        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
                        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>

                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
                            <ul class="form-list">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
                                <li>
                                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                            </ul>

                            <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="forgot-password" id="forgot-password"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="block-title">
                        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></span></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/forgotpasswordpost') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
                            <ul class="form-list">
                                <li>
                                    <label for="email" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" alt="email" id="email_address" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getEmailValue()) ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="forgot-password" id="back-login"><?php echo $this->__('Back to Login?'); ?></a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="new-users">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?>" class="button invert" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCreateAccountUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
        var dataForgetForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
        //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any caching modules enabled?

Comment: No we dont have nay cache modules

Comment: Did you change your store URL? It could be that the cookie domain is incorrect. You could empty the var/session folder to clean any previous sessions.

Comment: No not changed the URL, tried to empty the session folder but no luck

Comment: Check your Javascript code, if it open a popup, then JS make a ajax request to check the login credentials and trigger the popup on error. Google Chrome Console can show you what error are happening.

Comment: Does this happen if you revert back to the default theme?

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by a wrong template file, I have seen situations where the persistent  shopping cart template file was used (even when this function is switched off).

Check if your template has a `template/persustant/customer/form/login.phtml` file and remove this (or replace with a correct version from base/default).

If you have the persistent shopping cart enabled, try it with this option disabled `System=>Configuration=>Customer=>Persistent Shopping Cart=>Enable=>Set to No`.

Answer (score 1):

The request is processing by customer account controller `Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginPostAction().` File location is

app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Dig from here. I think the error that is generated when password do not match in customer `model. ie Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::authenticate().` There you can see this part

File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
 if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
 }
```

Dig more with this info

Comment: It adds an error if the authentication fails `$session->addError($message);` but how can I render the error in the frontend?